# EM wave generated with DC battery and coil?

Tags: electromagnetism

I did below experiment and wanted to confirm the spark is in deed Electro magnetic wave.

1) Took coil of wire , wound it over a iron rod.
2) connected one end of coil to +ve terminal  of battery and other to -ve . Rather touched one end of coil to +ve and other end to -ve.
3) Rapidly touch / untouch i.e( connect and disconnect  ) the wire end to  +ve  terminal, keeping wire connection to -ve terminal intact.
 every time I rapidly connect and disconnect the wire end to +ve terminal of battery, I saw a spark , is it EM wave ?

Comment: If you see a spark, it's probably a [current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current).

Comment: The spark proper isn't an em wave but the spark *creates* quite a bit broadband em radiation as a nearby functioning AM radio will reveal.  Early radio technology included spark gap transmitters:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSf93g0heUA

Comment: Ofcourse the spark created visible light,infrared rays etc but I think thats not what you mean?

Comment: Closing the connection allows current to flow, that creates a magnetic field to build. Opening the circuit attempts to stop current flow, the magnetic field that was previously built starts to collapse. This collapse induces the current to continue to flow by raising the voltage across the gap, creating a spark. The creation and quick collapse of the magnetic field is a magnetic wave, not the spark. Current in a transmitting antenna builds then collapses fast enough that the magnetic field that was expanding, never returns (magnetic losses), that is the radio signal. Elementary stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you see the spark (as Kyle Kanos) pointed out- this is a current passing through air - the electrons excite atoms/molecules to emit light, and this is the spark that you see. The current normally goes in a track, which is why the spark is a line.

Now, of course, light is an EM wave - so by generating light you have, in fact, generated an EM wave - or rather many many EM waves.

One final point is that the spark will also generate radio waves - if you try your experiment with an AM radio nearby you should be able to 'hear' intereference generated by your spark.